# How to define a react-query query key for related resources that do not include parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-query

Say I have multiple related queries:

1. `api/rewards/plan`
2. `api/rewards/achieved`

After a mutation, I need to refetch both queries.
What would be the recommended way to construct the query keys for the queries above and what would be the query key to provide `queryCache.refetchQueries`?

The [documented](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query#options) type of the query key parameter is:
`queryKey: String | [String, Variables: Object] | falsy | Function => queryKey`

Does this make sense?

1. `useQuery(["rewards", {plan: true}], ...)`
2. `useQuery(["rewards", {achieved: true}], ...)`
3. `queryCache.refetchQueries("rewards")`

Thanks